# Flask-Sqlalchemy compare session with database object

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm using Flask-SqlAlchemy and I would like to compare the current entity from the database with the one from the session. Challenge is that when I execute an additional query it always fetches the value from the session and not from db. What makes sense because both objects live in the same transaction. Any suggestion would be much appreciated.

```
 @expose('/edit/', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
    def edit_view(self):
       
        vehicle = Vehicle().query.get(request.args.get('id'))
        vehicle.status_id = 3
        db_vehicle = Vehicle().query.get(request.args.get('id'))
        if db_vehicle.status_id != vehicle.status_id:
            #     do some action
            pass
       
        db.session.add(vehicle)
        db.session.commit()
```

Comment: isnt it just  Vehicle.query.get(). if you call Vehicle() it creates new object in session

Comment: Its loads an instance from the db

Comment: Based on the code in the question, the simplest thing to do is to assign the original value to a temporary variable before updating it or, compare the retrieved value with `3` and execute your logic before updating.

Comment: The idea is actually to avoid the case where someone else changed the value and we run in data inconsistencies. Maybe my approach is wrong and I should go with locking.